# Is GAAP useful for personal budgeting?

Tags: budget

From analyzing securities, I am broadly familiar with GAAP. I'm not an accountant, if you threw a bunch of bank statements from a large company at me, I couldn't compose a GAAP-compliant annual report. However, I generally how they work.

I am looking for some guidelines so I can analyze my personal finances (mortgage, salary, debts) consistently. Instead of doing trial and error to reinvent accounting, I'm thinking why not just base it on something that's already worked out and familiar? My personal accounting is for my own use only (I won't use this for filing taxes, applying for loans, etc) so I don't actually need to be perfectly compliant. Just follow the basic principles of GAAP where they are useful, and ignore them where they are not.

Is this a reasonable approach, or are there aspects of GAAP that make it impractical or not useful (even if you pick and choose) for analyzing personal finances?

My goal is to have a consistent definition of what I consider asset vs. liability, short-term vs. long-term receivable, etc. After I accumulate several years of personal financial reviews, I want to have confidence they're all consistent, as opposed to "burning" the first few years with experimenting on definitions.

Comment: What problem(s) are you trying to solve?  Most individuals are better off with simple cash accounting.  Trying to depreciate personal assets, determining when to recognize revenue, etc. aren't good time investments for most people.

Comment: @JustinCave Consistent definition of what I consider asset vs. liability, short term vs. long term receivables, etc.

Comment: Can you give an example of what sort of things you think simple cash accounting would call an asset that is really a liability (or vice versa)?  Or examples of a long term receivable for an individual?  You may be in an unusual position for some reason (i.e. your personal finances may be dependent primarily on a self-employed consulting business, for example, that does have legitimate accounts receivable where aging is appropriate).

Comment: @JustinCave No, I cannot. I am not an accountant and I don't know all the corner cases that come up. I want to avoid spending time rediscovering those corner cases, and instead base my approach on something a real accountant has already figured out. Like GAAP.

Comment: @gomennathan the reason GAAP/IFRS exist is to compare between different businesses. You can define your own liabilities and assets any way you want, no-one is going to be using your own statements for comparison. Any underwriter you'd work with would be requesting statements from your banks, they won't believe your own word no matter the framework you chose to use.

Comment: @JustinCave The biggest flaw in personal finance is not capitalizing costs of cars. People who do services like Uber may simply not break even because they aren't capitalizing acquisition, insurance, and maintenance costs which often exceed direct fuel costs. Similar to that, many people get into financial issues when they don't properly accrue costs for their homes and major appliances. When something breaks or the roof springs a leak, they have to resort to expensive loans.

Answer (score 7):

GAAP (and similarly IFRS outside the US) are designed to be a comprehensive framework for business accounting. Their goal is not just to provide a framework, but to provide a *single* framework for everyone to use so that we could compare apples to apples when comparing financial reports.

For individuals this is meaningless. You don't have financial reporting, you don't have independent auditing, and you don't have books that someone else has to investigate and make financial decisions based on them.

If anyone needs to make financial decisions about you (e.g.: you're applying for a loan) - they'll ask for the documents they need and will compile them in the way they want.

If you want to keep books for yourself, then being a cash-based individual person you probably don't even need a double-book accounting system, you can just use an Excel spreadsheet.

So trying to apply the whole GAAP framework to your own individual self is a huge overkill and may be even infeasible.

Comment: Most personal finance programs are single-entry, though they could be forced to do something resembling double entry. But if you do want real double entry, GnuCash is the only one I know of really designed around that concept.